# Command line rar.exe and delete files from archive older than sytem date minus 14

Tags: windows, command-line, rar

I know there is a `d` command line switch but how do I add system date minus 14 for example?
I would like to remove from the archive `d:\Backup\Transactions` all the files older than 14 days.

So far I have this:

```
"c:\program files\winrar\rar.exe" a -mt2 -m1 -wd:\rartemp d:\Backup\Transactions f:\BACKUP\*.trn
```

I would like to add deletion part to this line or possibly a new command line before that.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You question isn't entirely clear; please clarify your specific problem.

Comment: Well i would like to remove from this archive d:\Backup\Transactions all the files older than 14 days.

Comment: And what's the operating system you're currently using? What did you try so far?

Comment: Windows 2003 is in use

Comment: What did you try so far? Don't know really what to try hence this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the archive is called `Transactions.rar`, so you can use the [-to](https://documentation.help/WinRAR/HELPSwTO.htm) switch.
To delete the files from the archive which are not modified in the last 14 days:

```
"c:\program files\winrar\rar.exe" d -tom14d d:\Backup\Transactions.rar
```

Comment: 8 years later finally comes the answer :)

Comment: @RicardoBohner Because I was looking for a similar question and Google brought me here... I wanted to delete/purge files in an archive if they're orphaned (i.e. not exist in the original location) for some days and this doesn't seem to be possible :-(